# reading a directory's files return null array

Tags: android, file, directory

I am now building an file sharing app in android and i have tried to get all the files on a certain directory (in my case it is the mp3 directory). while I was doing it using the function `File.listFiles()` it was returning null for no reason that I know of.

```
directorys = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/mp3");
        Log.d(TAG,directorys.listFiles().length+"");
```

after it an exception has be given for that listFiles is an null array?
btw I have used this permission

```
<uses-permission- android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/mp3";
Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
File directory = new File(path);
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ files.length);
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
    Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].getName());
}
```

and from marshmallow and above version you need to add permission programaticaly

```
public boolean requestForPermission() {

    boolean isPermissionOn = true;
    final int version = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (version >= 23) {
        if (!canAccessExternalSd()) {
            isPermissionOn = false;
            requestPermissions(EXTERNAL_PERMS, EXTERNAL_REQUEST);
        }
    }

    return isPermissionOn; }

public boolean canAccessExternalSd() {
    return (hasPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)); }

private boolean hasPermission(String perm) {
    return (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, perm));

}
```

Comment: i don't think it would , you can test it

Comment: i did, and it is still

Comment: i have edit my post would you try and see whats the result